# Windows Chat application with persistent desktop notifications?

Tags: windows, chat, notification

Are there any Windows chat or messaging apps that show a persistent desktop notification until acknowledged (when clicked)?

The only thing I have seen is software called Toaster(sp?) which works for Skype Business; surely that can't be the only thing out there.

Nothing related to an actual telephone or cell phone, this should be stand alone desktop client (like mirc, slack, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send messages between Windows computers over network](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/send-messages-between-windows-computers-over-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year or so ago, I worked at a company where a few of us were testing out [LAN Messenger](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lanmsngr/).

- Its open source and completely free.
- doesn't require a server.
- Works on Windows, Mac and Linux.
- Messages show persistently.
- It allows files transfers
- It allows for message history.

It hasn't been updated in awhile, but it seemed to work on Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Telegram](https://telegram.org/). Its best with notifications support

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned it cannot be a phone app or require a phone number. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Slack client has this feature. https://slack.com/downloads/windows

Comment: Slack desktop notifications does not have controllable desktop notifications times or persistence,  at least when tested it about a  month ago.